# Show new image onClick

Tags: java, android, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm making a quiz game. If the correct button if pressed (4 options) i want to show another picture. First picture is a questionmark, next picture is a picture of a person.

I have these two ImageViews

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/et"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/questionmark"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
```

Both in my RelativeLayout. ImageView2 is overlapping ImageView.
What is the best way to either switch between the picture or remove ImageView2?

If private button knapEt is pressed, ImageView2 should be removed or switched in layering, so ImageView is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple logic, at first only one of the view is shown the other is not visible using the `android:visibility="gone"` property.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:src="@drawable/et"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="19dp" 
android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageView
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView2"
android:src="@drawable/questionmark"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
```

then use the codes to toggle the image. each time it is clicked, the first one becomes invisible and the second one becomes visible and vice versa.

```
boolean flag = true;

public void toggleImage()
    {

            if (flag == true)
            {

                image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
            else
            {
                //make the background visible
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


    }
```

Comment: Just what i needed. Thanks :-)